# Why isn't my second HDMI alsa_output being detected at start-up?

Tags: 13.10, sound, pulseaudio

For some reason my audio output isn't being detected on boot-up or after issueing a `pulseaudio -k` command. Which means I can't set it as the default playback device.

The output for `pactl list short sinks` displays:

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

However, when I go in to the sound settings, it lists 3 devices:

- HDMI / DisplayPort 2 *(This is what I need to use)*
- HDMI / DisplayPort
- Analogue Output

Only once I've selected `HDMI / DisplayPort 2` in the sound settings does the output of `pactl list short sinks` change to:

```
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra1 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

At this point my `~/.config/pulse` default-sink file now lists the -extra1 device as I'd like. However, after typing `pulseaudio -k`; everything (including the default-sink file) switches back to the analog output. Presumably because it can't find the listed output.

Is there a reason where pulseaudio can't see this third output by default? What's Sound Manager doing to detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a work-around for this:

Go to Sound Settings and change the sound to HDMI / DisplayPort 2. Then close the settings window and run the following command:

```
pacmd dump | grep set-card-profile
```

Copy the output of the command above and paste it at the bottom of the */etc/pulse/default.pa* file (open it as root with a text editor, e.g.: "gksu /etc/pulse/default.pa")

Comment: Thanks, worked great.
I also had to add in the set-default-sink to that default.pa file for it to pick it up correctly